# How can I make the marker changing color while hover the text below it?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hope you are all fine. If you go over the marker, it'll change the color, but I would like this too when I hover the text which is below it. Is there anything that can allow the link between this 2 div ?

Here is the code :

```css
/* Point bleu sur le trait */

.marker:hover::before{
    border-color:  #258CC7;
    transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}


.marker { 
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #D5DBDB;
   margin-top: 10px;
   z-index: 3;
   transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}

/* Effet lorsque l'on passe la souris sur le market */

.marker:hover {
   background-color: #424949;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name ="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
  </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="timeline-container">
            <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
                <div class="test3">
                    <div class="marker"></div>
                    <div class="timeline-content">
                        <h3>TEST TEST</h3>
                        <span>Haec igitur prima lex amicitiae sanciatur, ut ab amicis honesta petamus, amicorum causa honesta faciamus, ne exspectemus quidem, dum rogemur; studium semper adsit, cunctatio absit; consilium vero dare audeamus libere. Plurimum in amicitia amicorum bene suadentium valeat auctoritas, eaque et adhibeatur ad monendum non modo aperte sed etiam acriter, si res postulabit, et adhibitae pareatur.</span>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Cordially

Comment: Since there will probably be a bunch of answers, let me answer your question in short: you can't affect a div based on its **immediately next** sibling in CSS. If `container` contains `div1` and `div2` in that order, you can change `div2` based on something that happens to `div1`, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by moving the `:hover` part to the `.test3` element, creating a selector like this:

```css
.test3:hover .marker {
   ...
}
```

All together:

```css
/* Point bleu sur le trait */

.marker:hover::before{
    border-color:  #258CC7;
    transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}


.marker { 
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #D5DBDB;
   margin-top: 10px;
   z-index: 3;
   transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}

/* Effet lorsque l'on passe la souris sur le market */

.test3:hover .marker {
   background-color: #424949;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name ="author" content="Ismaël Zemmouj">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
  </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="timeline-container">
            <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
                <div class="test3">
                    <div class="marker"></div>
                    <div class="timeline-content">
                        <h3>TEST TEST</h3>
                        <span>Haec igitur prima lex amicitiae sanciatur, ut ab amicis honesta petamus, amicorum causa honesta faciamus, ne exspectemus quidem, dum rogemur; studium semper adsit, cunctatio absit; consilium vero dare audeamus libere. Plurimum in amicitia amicorum bene suadentium valeat auctoritas, eaque et adhibeatur ad monendum non modo aperte sed etiam acriter, si res postulabit, et adhibitae pareatur.</span>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by transitioning on `timeline-block` instead since it is the parent element of both marker and `timeline-content`.

```css
/* Point bleu sur le trait */

.timeline-block:hover::before{
    border-color:  #258CC7;
    transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.timeline-block{
transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}

.marker { 
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #D5DBDB;
   margin-top: 10px;
   z-index: 3;
   
}

/* Effet lorsque l'on passe la souris sur le market */

.timeline-block:hover {
   background-color: #424949;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name ="author" content="Ismaël Zemmouj">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
  </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="timeline-container">
            <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
                <div class="test3">
                    <div class="marker"></div>
                    <div class="timeline-content">
                        <h3>TEST TEST</h3>
                        <span>Haec igitur prima lex amicitiae sanciatur, ut ab amicis honesta petamus, amicorum causa honesta faciamus, ne exspectemus quidem, dum rogemur; studium semper adsit, cunctatio absit; consilium vero dare audeamus libere. Plurimum in amicitia amicorum bene suadentium valeat auctoritas, eaque et adhibeatur ad monendum non modo aperte sed etiam acriter, si res postulabit, et adhibitae pareatur.</span>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Point bleu sur le trait */

.marker:hover::before{
    border-color:  #258CC7;
    transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}


.marker { 
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #D5DBDB;
   margin-top: 10px;
   z-index: 3;
   transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}

/* Effet lorsque l'on passe la souris sur le market */

.test3:hover .marker {
   background-color: #424949;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name ="author" content="Ismaël Zemmouj">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
  </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="timeline-container">
            <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
                <div class="test3">
                    <div class="marker"></div>
                    <div class="timeline-content">
                        <h3>TEST TEST</h3>
                        <span>Haec igitur prima lex amicitiae sanciatur, ut ab amicis honesta petamus, amicorum causa honesta faciamus, ne exspectemus quidem, dum rogemur; studium semper adsit, cunctatio absit; consilium vero dare audeamus libere. Plurimum in amicitia amicorum bene suadentium valeat auctoritas, eaque et adhibeatur ad monendum non modo aperte sed etiam acriter, si res postulabit, et adhibitae pareatur.</span>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, then I suppose I can give a simple jquery solution using the `hover()` method with the addition and removing of a class.

If you don't like this method, it might be useful to someone else.

```
$('.timeline-content').hover(enter, leave);

function enter() {
  $('.marker').addClass('hover');
};

function leave() {
  $('.marker').removeClass('hover');
};
```

And css:

```
.hover {
   background-color: #424949;
   transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out; 
}
```

```js
$('.timeline-content').hover(enter, leave);

function enter() {
  $('.marker').addClass('hover');
};

function leave() {
  $('.marker').removeClass('hover');
};
```

```css
/* Point bleu sur le trait */

/*.marker:hover::before{
    border-color:  #258CC7;
    transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out;
}*/


.marker { 
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #D5DBDB;
   margin-top: 10px;
   z-index: 3;
   transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}

/* Effet lorsque l'on passe la souris sur le market */

/*.marker:hover {
   background-color: #424949;
}*/

.hover {
   background-color: #424949;
   transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name ="author" content="Ismaël Zemmouj">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
  </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="timeline-container">
            <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
                <div class="test3">
                    <div class="marker"></div>
                    <div class="timeline-content">
                        <h3>TEST TEST</h3>
                        <span>Haec igitur prima lex amicitiae sanciatur, ut ab amicis honesta petamus, amicorum causa honesta faciamus, ne exspectemus quidem, dum rogemur; studium semper adsit, cunctatio absit; consilium vero dare audeamus libere. Plurimum in amicitia amicorum bene suadentium valeat auctoritas, eaque et adhibeatur ad monendum non modo aperte sed etiam acriter, si res postulabit, et adhibitae pareatur.</span>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```